# How to use the mouse in Midnight Commander when running Alpine in Docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, alpine-linux, mc

I like using the mouse in Midnight Commander. I can easily select files, folders and features with the mouse. To do so, I use the following steps:

```
docker run -it ubuntu sh
apt update
apt install mc
mc
```

Then I use the mouse. It is working fine in this Docker container. The example shown above uses Ubuntu.

However, when using Alpine instead, MC itself is working but mouse support in MC is not. The steps I use to try are just the Alpine equivalents of what I showed above.

```
docker run -it alpine sh
apk update
apk install mc
mc
```

I am running Docker on a Windows 10 Device and I use the command prompt but that should not matter. Hopefully, someone can explain how to enable mouse the support for MC in my Alpine container.

Answer (score 1):

Alpine Linux disables mouse support in midnight commander by configuring it with

```
./configure \
 [...] \
 --without-gpm-mouse \
```

(https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/mc/APKBUILD). If you require mouse support, you will need to [build your own midnight commander package](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Creating_an_Alpine_package) that passes `--with-gpm-mouse` to configure and adds the correct dependencies (`gpm`).

Comment: What git repository url do I need? The APKBUILD link your shared does not work.

Comment: That's not a URL to a repository you can pass to git directly, but you can open it in your browser :) https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/ has URLs for cloning: git://git.alpinelinux.org/aports and https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports

Comment: But which git url (for cloning) specificly do I need for Midnight Commander?

Comment: Either is fine. The APKBUILD for midnight commander is in the `main/mc` subdirectory.